# Get a local file from plugin to javascript

Tags: javascript, image, file, google-chrome, plugins

I have developped a brower plugin that Acquire a picture from a Scanner or a Camera and save the picture in the file system of the user.
The output is the filepath to the picture.
I want to preview the picture in the Broswer, using javascript...

How can I get the picture without user interaction ?

( part of a Web App only compatible with Google Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the filepath returned by your browser plugin and you have identified the event when you have to display the image then you can call `ShowImage(filepath)` function on that event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(filePath) {
        $("#preview").append("<img alt='img' src='" + filePath + "'");
    }
</script>
```

Your HTML should contain the div:

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the FileReader but it seems to be not working with an absolute path

Comment: One pre-requisite in this scenario is that you have to provide `filepath` as Absolute path not as Physical path

Answer (score 1):

If you have the contents of the image already you can load them in directly, by base64 encoding it and providing an URL as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm working with HD Image, and base64 encoding give me a really too big string to manipulate.

Comment: @user2385830 You do not need to manipulate it, just insert in into the DOM. Are you certain this won't work?

Comment: I tried to return base64 string from my NPAPI plugin, and it crashes Chrome every time.